# regex - confused - first part of string to match only

Tags: regex

I have a variable length string and want to match only the first 16 characters if this string is over 8.

An example:
    testertestertestertestertesterte

My regex is:

```
([a-zA-Z1-9_]{8,16})
```

However, instead of matching:

```
testertestertest
```

It matches the whole string - 1 time for each 16 characters.

How can this be limited to the first match only?

Comment: Which flavor of regex are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put an anchor on the RegEx pattern to indicate the match should be at the beginning of the line:

```
^([a-zA-Z1-9_]{8,16})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could anchor the search to the start of the string with `^`

```
^([a-zA-Z1-9_]{8,16})
```

If you want it to match if there are *more* than 8 characters in the string, you will need to adjust the 8 to 9 as well.

```
^([a-zA-Z1-9_]{9,16})
```